# Unable to execute binary file. Exec format error

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit, nodejs

I recently heard about [Breach](http://breach.cc/), a Node.js based browser. I was following the instructions on http://codeforgeek.com/2014/08/download-install-breach-browser-ubuntu-14-04/ to install it but got the following error :

**breach-v0.3.22-alpha.6-linux-x64/__AUTO_UPDATE_BUNDLE__/exo_browser/exo_browser: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error**

After some googling, I found that it is because I am trying to install the 64 bit package on the 32 bit Ubuntu installation. I tried to find 32 bit package of the same but ended up with no luck. The browser is only available in 64 bit packet(as far as i know).

So, My question is :

Is it possible to somehow install it on the 32 bit OS or if any program available which can run 64 bit applications on the 32 bit OS.

I have been googling around and found no help. Can anyone help me?

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 (32 Bit).

Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Not natively. You could try using qemu user mode emulation, and binfmt_misc to make it the interpreter for x86_64 ELF binaries.